# How to Display Month and Year in xAxis of Highcharts datetime graph

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have an dateline type of graph displayed using both angularjs and highcharts. The date value is retreived from JSON response as say 20120905(YYYYMMDD). As i have read in many forums I converted my date to UTC format for plotting in graph. The graph is plotted correctly, but my xaxis is dispalying on they UTC values like 1,370G for all the date time values.

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: '% of Accounts',
                data: outerSeries   /* Contains the data  similar to this. [[1368835200000, 2.9], [1371513600000, 0.5], [1374105600000, 1.94], [1376784000000, 1.44], [1379462400000, 1.18]] */
            }],  
            title: {
             text: tableTitle
            },
            xAxis: [{

                labels: {format: '{value:%Y}' },
                /*dateTimeLabelFormats:{
                  month:'%Y',
                  year:'%Y'
                },*/
              type:"datetime"
            }],
            yAxis: {title: {text: 'TestReport'}},
            tooltip: {
              formatter: function() {
              var myDate = new Date(this.x);
              var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(),myDate.getUTCMonth()-1,myDate.getUTCDate());
              return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', newDateMs) +': '+ this.y;}
            },
            //xAxis: {currentMin: 0, currentMax: 10, minRange: 1, title:{text:'Time Period'}},
            //xAxis: {ordinal:false,type:'datetime', dateTimeLabelFormats: {  year: '%b%Y' }, title:{text:'Time Period'}},
            loading: false
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only thing you need to change is the configuration for xAxis.

Try the following(only highlight the xAxis part):

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
        // other configuration
        xAxis: {
          type:"datetime",
          dateTimeLabelFormats:{
            month: '%b %e, %Y'
          }  // label in x axis will be displayed like Jan 1, 2012
        },
        // other configuration
}
```

I used your sample data and created a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WEgmq/1/

Feel free to play with the fiddle. And you might aware that, if you comment out `type:"datetime"`, the xAxis will display the label like 1,370G as you mentioned.
Also, since the interval of your sample data is one month, the label format of xAxis won't be changed if you configure `day` format in `dateTimeLabelFormats`. Instead, you need to configure the `month` format since the minimum interval is one month.

Playing with the `dateTimeLabelFormats`, `minTickInterval` you can obtain what you want.

Comment: I tried what you have said. but I am still getting the same issue. No change at all in my xaxis labels.

Comment: @user544808 I used your sample data and created a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WEgmq/1/ I also updated the answer with some explanation about the fiddle. Hope it can help you.

Comment: It's also required to remove: `labels: {format: '{value:%Y}' },`.